# Is possible to pass to a function the properties of an object without the arguments defined and use them by the object's keys?

Tags: javascript

Quick and strange question:

I have an object (in this example is small but in the project is larger):

```
var myObject = {
   hello: 1, // easier I think
   'hey.ya': 5 // quite impossible but the first option is valid too
}
```

then I want to pass somehow to a function and use "hello" for example in a closure like this

```
function x(){
// my closure
   return function(){this.init = function(){alert(hello)}, this.heyYa = function(){alert(/* I do not know how to call the other hey.ya variable */)}}
}

var myClass = x(), instance = new myClass(); instance.init();
```

thanks!

Comment: Where is `myObject` in all this? To call 'hey.ya' you call `myObject['hey.ya']`.

Comment: What do you mean by *"without the arguments defined"*? Do you mean without defining a *parameter* in the function?

Comment: If you wanted to access the properties of the object in the function as *variables* in the function, you won't be able to without anticipating the object being passed, and using `.eval()` *(which you shouldn't do)*. Even then, `hey.ya` won't work as a variable identifier.

Comment: ok, then seems to be impossible.. (eval can't be used)

Comment: Yeah, your best bet will be to just reference the object passed as a formal parameter to the function, and access the properties in the typical way.

Comment: ...well, there is the `with` statement, but it is generally avoided, and is not allowed if you're running your code in *strict mode*, and you'd still need to change `hey.ya` to be a valid variable identifier.

Comment: with is bad too, I know.. anyway this was not so important, only more for a code-design aspect. But thanks anyway for your time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the myObject

```
var myObject = {
   hello: 1,
   'hey.ya': 5
}

function x(obj){
   return function(){
       this.init = function(){
           alert(obj.hello)
       }, 
       this.heyYa = function(){
           alert(obj['hey.ya'])
       }
   }
}

var myClass = x(myObject);
var instance = new myClass(); 
instance.init(); // alerts '1'
instance.heyYa(); // alerts '5'
```

Comment: you need to pass in myObject in x();

Comment: You really don't need to pass it as long as you access it by the `myObject` identifier.

Comment: @patrick dw: true, but I'm assuming he wants to be able to create multiple with different 'myObject' values...

Comment: Yes, but even if you create multiple functions via `x()`, you're still passing in the same object via `myObject`, so they'll all share the same instance just as they would if you referenced it directly.

Comment: the myObject must be passed somehow as the other function doesn't have direct access. But this is how actually things are done, I only wanted to know if it could be possible to have the other syntax...